# Macでのバックスラッシュ「\」の入力方法

Tags: macos

PyCharmをMacで使っていますが、入力時にバックスラッシュ「\」が使えなくて設定を変えようといろいろ探してみましたが見つかりませんでした。

もしわかる方いらっしゃれば教えていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: 僕はいつもキーボードをUSモードで使っています。日本語のローマ字モードだと入らないようです。

Comment: 自己解決しました。
option + ¥　で表示されました。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Option</kbd>キーと<kbd>¥</kbd>キーを同時に押すと入力出来るようです。

---

<kbd>Option</kbd>キーというのは、Mac向けキーボードに特有のキーです。
  大抵の場合はキーボードの最下段（スペースキーのある段）に配置されています。
  「Option」と刻印されていますが、「⌥」や「ALt」の刻印がある場合もあります。
   Mac向けでないキーボードでは、<kbd>Alt</kbd>キーが相当します。
  参考: [オプションキー (Wikipedia)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AA%E3%83%97%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AD%E3%83%BC)