# ¥"で"を表示させようとしましたがエラーになります

Tags: ruby

書籍にrubyで

```
puts " ¥"Hello¥" "
```

と記述して実行すると

```
"Hello"
```

なると記載されているのですが、

```
syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting end-of-input
puts " ¥"Hello"
```

上記のようなエラーが出ます。書籍の記述間違いでしょうか。

Comment: 環境も記載するといいかと思います。またご利用の環境はバックスラッシュの環境だったりしませんか？

Comment: cloud9とsublimetext、ターミナルの２つの環境でやりました
そういえばmacなのでバックスラッシュの環境です
やってみます

Comment: puts " ¥"Hello¥" " はだめで puts " \"Hello\" " で動くとかでしょうか？

Comment: 参考: [Macでのバックスラッシュ「\」の入力方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/22936/3054)

Comment: " \"Hello\" " でいけました！
ありがとうございます
すっきりしました

Comment: @yock 解決したようでよかったです。ちょうどsayuriさんが回答しているので同じ内容ですし承認してあげてください。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`¥`（円記号；U+00A5）](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%86%86%E8%A8%98%E5%8F%B7)と[`\`（バックスラッシュ；U+005C）](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%90%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9%E3%83%A9%E3%83%83%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5)は別の文字です。
なお、質問タイトルある`“”`（ダブル引用符；U+201C、U+201D）も`"`（引用符；U+0022）とは別の文字です。

Rubyを含む多くの言語では`"`（引用符；U+0022）を`\`（バックスラッシュ；U+005C）でエスケープします。

Comment: おかげで記載通りの表示になりました
助かります　ありがとうございます